# jquery javascript navigation (redirection) issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

the project is in MVC and i used this code in _Layout page
and the control txtSearch is in layout page too

what below code doing is
when i write something on text (txtSearch) and press enter that redirect to stockList page with entered parameter

```
$('#txtSearch').keypress(function(event) {
  debugger;
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '13') {
    var strUrl = '/stocklist/All%20Categories-All%20Makers-All%20Models-0-0-' + $('#txtSearch').val();
    location.href = strUrl;
  }
});
```

what problem i got is in some page this action working very fine but while comes to stocklist page its not working properly
will you please help me out from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#txtSearch').keypress(function (event) {
    debugger;
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        var strUrl = '/stocklist/All%20Categories-All%20Makers-All%20Models-0-0-' + $('#txtSearch').val();
        location.href = strUrl;
        return false;
    }
});
```

just add **return false;** in end of the code